# Filtering SqlDataSource by gridview cell

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I've created a simple `.aspx` page which contains one main gridview (GridView1) and the second gridview (GridView2) is in the template field of the first one.

There are 2 `SqlDataSource`s for these gridviews (`SqlDataSource1` and `SqlDataSource2`).

Is it possible to filter rows in the `SqlDataDource2` (or GridView2) by the value from the `SqlDataSource1` (or GridView1)?

I mean that for the each row in the GridView1 there will be only rows from GridView2 where the fields GridView2.PlaceID and GridView1.PlaceID are equal.
Now we see all rows from the GridView2 for each row from the GridView1.

The code is here:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB Places %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PlaceID], [Place] FROM [Places]" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB Devices %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PlaceID], [DeviceID], [Date] FROM [Devices]"  ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Код_места" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PlaceID" HeaderText="PlaceID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PlaceID">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Place" HeaderText="Place" SortExpression="Place">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" HeaderText="Devices">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView id="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PlaceID" HeaderText="PlaceID" SortExpression="PlaceID">
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DeviceID" HeaderText="DeviceID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DeviceID">
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date">
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to place `SqlDataSource2` into your `TemplateField` together with  `GridView2` and add `parameter`(s) from fields in `GridView1`.

Comment: Could you be so kind to give me some code example? Because I understand that I need to add parameter, but  I don't know how to link this parameter in sqldatasource with the gridview cell value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated

You need to place `SqlDataSource2` inside `asp:TemplateField` and set `defaultValue` from inside `.cs` code (`GridView1_RowDataBound`).  Something like this. Also read [MSDN Walkthrough: Creating a Nested GridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038.aspx)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB Places %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PlaceID], [Place] FROM [Places]" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PlaceID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PlaceID" HeaderText="PlaceID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PlaceID">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Place" HeaderText="Place" SortExpression="Place">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" HeaderText="Devices">
            <ItemTemplate>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB Devices %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [PlaceID], [DeviceID], [Date] FROM [Devices] where PlaceID=@placeid"  ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
   <SelectParameters>
     <asp:Parameter name="placeid" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" />
</asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:GridView id="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PlaceID" HeaderText="PlaceID" SortExpression="PlaceID">
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DeviceID" HeaderText="DeviceID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DeviceID">
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date">
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</form>

//.cs
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
     //Find data source and set value for parameter
        ((SqlDataSource)e.Row.FindControl("SqlDataSource2")).SelectParameters["placeid"].DefaultValue = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["placeid"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex! I've tried, but it's a new problem. The first problem was the exception **Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event**, I've found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527429/why-has-moving-gridview-code-to-an-ascx-given-an-databinding-expressions-are-on) and changed _<%#_ to _<%=_. But after this when I'm opening the page I'm receiving the exception **System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.** Do you have any ideas what else should I need to do?